# How to use OAuth2 with requests get

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, typeerror

What wrong in my code? I'm trying to send an API request and getting an error:

> 'OAuth2Session' object is not callable

```
import requests
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
client_id = '111'
username = '222'
password = '333'
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
headers = {

    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
}
url = "https://<API datasourse>"
response = requests.get(
     url,
    auth=oauth,
    headers=headers,
    verify=False
)
print(response.json())`
```

I'm trying to send an API request and getting an error:

> "'OAuth2Session' object is not callable"

how should I use this authorization?

Comment: check my answer below, i hope it will solve your problem. Let me know.

Comment: thank u very much, i will try this tomorrow, but i think it will work

Comment: If you, upvote my answer or accept it as an answer, it will help me grow my stackoverflow reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are using the OAuth2Session object as if it's a function, which is causing the error. Instead, you should use the fetch_token method to obtain the access token before making the API request.

The following code should work imo:

```
import requests
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

client_id = '111'
client_secret = 'your_client_secret'  # Don't hardcode this, use a secure method to store it
token_url = 'https://<token_endpoint>'  # Replace with the actual token endpoint URL

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}'
}

url = "https://<API_datasource>"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

print(response.json())
```

**Be sure to change 'your_client_secret' to your real secret code for your OAuth2 tool, and switch '<token_endpoint>' with the actual place where you get tokens. Also, think about keeping secret info safe, like your client codes.
This code gets the access pass using the fetch_token action, and then puts it in the headers for the API request using the 'Authorization' label.**